# Error message 'Expected ; after top level declarator ' 'Unknown type name import' with the bridge to use Swift in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I Have a message error when I try to add a bridge to use Swift in Objective-C.

Here is my code :

```
    import UIKit

    @objc class ScanViewController : UIViewController, IRLScannerViewControllerDelegate
    {
        var scan: Int = 0 //FIXME:delegate to put in swift
        var category: String = "" //FIXME:delegate to put in swift
...
```

Here is my bridge in Swift :

```
//  Bridging.swift
//  Created by OlostA on 10/06/2016.

import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc class Hello: NSObject {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hi there!")
    }
}
```

Here is my Objective-C file :

```
#import "CategoryViewController.h"
#import "ScanViewController.swift"
#import "GoFact-Swift.h"
@interface CategoryViewController ()
@end
@implementation CategoryViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"])
    {
        ScanViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.category = sender;
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to remove

```
#import "ScanViewController.swift"
```

It should be ok then.